# So I'm trying to have it when you click a sign it makes it seem like your game is being hacked plz help me I'm on bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

ONLY using signs thxs! and only on BEDROCK edition not java

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: well nothing realy.

Comment: but i need to be on bedrock edition

Comment: and i know nothing

Comment: I'm no good at commands